# How to render a pug view without removing existing data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, pugjs

For example, I have a pug view 'VIEW.pug', it contains two parts

- part A: with some data
- part B: empty

after request a GET from express/node, I would like to keep part A's data and refresh part B with new data by using the res.render('VIEW', {xxx}) function.

So how can I make this happen? Once I render VIEW.pug, though I refresh part B with the correct data, but the data in part A are gone.

I wanna both of part A and part B have data, A with old existing data, and B with new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a **layout.pug** file :

```
html
  head
    title My Site - #{title}
    block scripts
      script(src='/jquery.js')
  body
    block content
```

now create a file with **partA.pug** , which extends layout file :

```
-extends layout.pug
  block content
  h1= PART A
```

now use **include**  to include partB in partA file

```
 include includes/partB.pug
```

your **partB.pug** should be rendered based on condition

```
#partB
- if(section=== 'DEMO-1') {
| <p>DEMO 1</p>
- }
- if(section === 'DEMO-2') {
| <p>DEMO 2</p>
- }
```

app.js

```
var express=require('express');
let app = express();
app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));


app.get('/demo1',function(req,res){
   return res.render("partA",{section:'DEMO-1'});
});

app.get('/demo2',function(req,res){
   return res.render("partA",{section:'DEMO-2'});
});
```